# How to access cached browsing history before Safari.app is closed?

Tags: terminal, safari, macos-catalina

On MacOS Catalina, Safari.app stores the browsing history in an sqlite3 database at `~/Library/Safari/History.db`.

This database is only updated when the app is fully closed (quit) for instance using `⌘q`.

How and where can I read the cached history before the app is quit? There must be another database file somewhere but I can't find it.